# Count combined with select distinct

Tags: sql, select, count

actually i try to find a way to select all distinct private message from a table and also got the count of each in 1 sql query

the actual table have column with the id of the member and also a column 
with the actual view state of the message when the message state = 0 it mean 
not read

example of data in table

```
roger 0
paul 1
roger 0
paul 0
mike 0
mike 0
mike 0
```

then the result i want is

```
roger 2
paul 1
mike 3
```

any help will be apreciated thanks

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: hmm honestly i dont know i use mysql i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```sql
SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM messages
 WHERE state = 0
 GROUP BY member_id
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=eef33b9d85f68b66abfbfde1b4097e69) demo

---

> I need also to select all field from another table that will match the member_id is that possible in 1 query

Sure,  `JOIN` away

```sql
SELECT m.*, t.*
  FROM (
    SELECT member_id, COUNT(*) AS count
      FROM messages
     WHERE state = 0
     GROUP BY member_id
) m JOIN other_table t
    ON m.member_id = t.member_id
```

Comment: thanks but i forgot 1 parameter in the question very sorry i need also to select all field from another table that will match the member_id is that possible in 1 query ? lets call that other table users

Comment: See the updated answer and don't forget to include all essential details in your question in the future :)

Comment: can i ask you is this better than doing a subquery ? actually i think it is but just want to be sure cause my subquery was running 10 000 time when i had 10 000 logs